# How can I create a Custom Page? (not a page template!!)

Tags: customization, pages

I would like to have inside my theme folder, a folder where I can leave all the portion of code and snippets that I don't want to use anymore or I just want to save for a while, and accessible every time I want to check it in the browser, the same way I usually do with frontpage.php. Something I can access through the link: http://localhost:8888/mydomain.com/temporary/page1.php
http://localhost:8888/mydomain.com/temporary/page2.php
http://localhost:8888/mydomain.com/temporary/page3.php

pd: i'm using understrap-child-master

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Try it out.  They will exist outside of WordPress though so they won't be editable by the dashboard and won't call any WordPress features (head, css, footer etc).

Comment: But I need loops and all the wordpress code to work..

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

1. I create a new file in a new folder in my theme, called prova.php and I "initialized" it as a template page introducing this line:

`<?php /*  Name: Prova */ ?>`

2. Then I create a new page in the wordpress admin, and i set it to use my new file as layout.
3. Now I can modify the file as I want using html, css, js, wordpress code etc.. and see the changes at localhost:8888/mydomanin.com/prova/